# Javascript number format issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four number formats '123 456,78', '123.456,78', '123'456.78', '123,456.78' in my application with dynamic decimal point. Is there any library or method in Javascript to Format number and remove format method?

Comment: Format how exactly, what do you expect to get ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>

var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0');
// '1,000'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several functions on the Number class that give you formatting of numbers:

```
var n = 5.1234567;
var sf = n.toFixed();
var se = n.toExponential();
var sp = n.toPrecision();
```

You can find details about these functions here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

More or less, these are equivalent to the %f and %g in C/C++ printf() format with just a size representing the number of digits to display.